# how can I print the final matrix correctly?

Tags: c

Problem Statement

A matrix is a 2D array of numbers arranged in rows and columns. We give you a Matrix of `N` rows and `M` columns.

Now your task is to do this operation on this matrix:

- If the value matches with the current row and column number then add `3` with the value.
- If the value matches with only the current row number then add `2` with the value.
- If the value matches with only the current column number then add `1` with the value.

Input Format

- The first line contains `N` is the number of rows in this matrix and `M` is the number of columns in this matrix
- The second line contains a 2D array `Arr[i][j]`.

Constraints

- `1 <= N, M <= 10`
- `0 <= Arr[i][j] <= 100`

Output Format

```
Print the matrix after the operation is done.
```

Sample Input 0

```
3 3
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

Sample Output 0

```
4 3 3 
2 1 1 
2 1 1
```

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(){

    //here taking the row and column from the users

    int row;

    int column, temp;

    printf("enter row and column\n");

    scanf("%d%d", &row, &column);

    int arr[row][column];

    //here taking the matrix input through the users

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){

            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);

        }
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<column; j++ ){
            if (arr[i][j] == arr[i+1] && arr[i][j]== arr[j+1]){
                    temp= arr[i][j]+3;
                    printf("%d", temp);

            }
            else if (arr[i][j] == arr[i+1]){
                temp= arr[i][j]+ 2;
                printf("%d", temp);
            }
            else if (arr[i][j]== arr[j+1]){
                temp= arr[i][j]+ 1;
                printf("%d", temp);
            }
            else{
                temp= arr[i][j];
                printf("%d", temp);
            }
        }
    }


    }
    return 0;

}
```

After I run the code, this doesn't work.

Comment: you are over thinking , the comparisons just need to be `arr[i][j]` with `i` and `j`

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. Can you clearly explain?

Comment: you are misreading the instructions; you just have to compare the contents of ar[i][j] with i and j. Look at the sample. arr[1][1] is in row 1 col 1. so it gets 3 added to it

Answer (score 1):

At least this issue:

`if (arr[i][j] == arr[i+1] && arr[i][j]== arr[j+1]){` is *undefined behavior* (UB) as code attempts to access outside `int arr[row][column];` with `arr[i+1]` and `arr[j+1]`.

`arr[i][j] == arr[i+1]` is not sensible as it attempts to compare an `int` with a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In c, there are two types of memories. One of them is run-time memory, where your program dynamically allocates memory based on actions done in the program execution time.

In your answer, you are setting your matrix size based on the numbers inputed by the user, which is dynamic memory.

A static array(what you are using) is not dynamic and it is the reason that you can't add more elements and change the size of it.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-memory-allocation-in-c-using-malloc-calloc-free-and-realloc/amp/

Comment: There's no such thing as *types of memories*. There's a stack, and there's a heap.

Comment: ... also register memory and other implementation dependent types.

Comment: Just a note going forward "geegsforgeeks.org" is not any type of primary authority on the C language (and off the record, is often flat-wrong or incomplete). Perhaps [C18 Standard (n2596)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf) would be a better reference.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Of course memory doesn't have types like a variable. I meant compilation time and run time

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin To be honest I learnt c, by clicking on random stuff, while making projects and I always found pdfs, books and large documentations as intimidating